# Spinner Looses focus on selection when keyboard opened

Tags: android, focus, android-spinner

in my layout I have several `EditText` and Spinners representing a form. everything works fins until I select `EditText` and keyboard gets open and activity is `adjustResize` then as I select spinner item after scrolling to bottom my activity scrolls to top and I will have to scroll back to bottom again.

**My XML:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    >

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/nsV"
        >

            <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/tell_us_about"
            style="@style/BoldStyle"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            />

            <!-- Price section -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"

                >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/price_with_curr"
                    style="@style/BoldStyle"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="*"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/Edit_Square"
                android:id="@+id/price_et"
                android:cursorVisible="true"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                />

            <!-- vehicle condition -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/condition"
                    style="@style/BoldStyle"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="*"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/spinner_style"
                android:id="@+id/condition_spinner"
                ></Spinner>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/body_style"
                    style="@style/BoldStyle"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/spinner_style"
                android:id="@+id/body_type_spinner"
                ></Spinner>

            <!-- odo meter -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"

                >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/km"
                    style="@style/BoldStyle"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="*"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/Edit_Square"
                android:id="@+id/odo_et"
                android:cursorVisible="true"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                />

            <!-- engine size-->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/engine_size"
                    style="@style/BoldStyle"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/spinner_style"
                android:id="@+id/engine_size_spinner"
                ></Spinner>

            <!-- transimssion -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/transmission"
                    style="@style/BoldStyle"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="*"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/spinner_style"
                android:id="@+id/transmission_spinner"
                ></Spinner>

            <!-- fuel type -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/fuel_type"
                    style="@style/BoldStyle"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="*"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/spinner_style"
                android:id="@+id/fuel_type_spinner"
                ></Spinner>

<!-- drive train-->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/drive_train"
                    style="@style/BoldStyle"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/spinner_style"
                android:id="@+id/drive_train_spinner"
                ></Spinner>

            <!-- engine capacity -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/eng_cap"
                    style="@style/BoldStyle"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/spinner_style"
                android:id="@+id/engine_capacity_spinner"
                ></Spinner>

            <!-- exterior color-->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/ext_color"
                    style="@style/BoldStyle"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="*"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/spinner_style"
                android:id="@+id/exterior_color_spinner"
                ></Spinner>

            <!-- interior color -->

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/int_color"
                    style="@style/BoldStyle"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="*"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/spinner_style"
                android:id="@+id/interior_color_spinner"
                ></Spinner>

            <!-- waranty -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/waranty"
                    style="@style/BoldStyle"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                >
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                    >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:id="@+id/yes"
                        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/yes_check"
                        android:paddingTop="2dp"
                        android:text="@string/yes"
                        android:textSize="11sp"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/yes_check"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:checked="false"

                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:lineSpacingExtra="10dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/blue"

                        android:theme="@style/CustomStyledRadioButton" />

                </RelativeLayout>
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                    >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                        android:id="@+id/no"
                        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/no_check"
                        android:paddingTop="2dp"
                        android:text="@string/no"
                        android:textSize="11sp"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        />

                    <CheckBox
                        android:id="@+id/no_check"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:checked="false"

                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:lineSpacingExtra="10dp"
                        android:textColor="@color/blue"

                        android:theme="@style/CustomStyledRadioButton" />

                </RelativeLayout>
            </LinearLayout>


            <!-- waranty_extra -->


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/waranty_extra"
                android:visibility="gone"
                >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"

                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/waranty_exipre_date"
                        style="@style/BoldStyle"
                        android:textSize="13sp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>

                <EditText
                    android:focusable="false"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    style="@style/Edit_Square"
                    android:id="@+id/waranty_exp_et"
                    android:inputType="date"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                    />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"

                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/waranty_expire_km"
                        style="@style/BoldStyle"
                        android:textSize="13sp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    style="@style/Edit_Square"
                    android:id="@+id/waranty_exp_km_et"
                    android:cursorVisible="true"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>


            <!-- description en-->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:id="@+id/desc_wrap_en"

            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"

                >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/description_en"
                    style="@style/BoldStyle"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/desc_et"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/square_border_grey"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:minLines="6"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textColorHighlight="@color/colorSubSecondary"
                />
</LinearLayout>

            <!-- description ar -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:id="@+id/desc_wrap"
                android:visibility="gone"
                >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"

                    >
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/description_ar"
                        style="@style/BoldStyle"
                        android:textSize="13sp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/desc_et_ar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/square_border_grey"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:minLines="6"
                    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:padding="5dp"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

            <!-- seller comments -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/seller_comments_wrap_en"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"

                >
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/seller_comment_en"
                    style="@style/BoldStyle"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/seller_comments_et"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/square_border_grey"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:minLines="6"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                />

</LinearLayout>


            <Button

                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/submit_btn"
                android:text="@string/continue_txt"
                android:background="@drawable/btn_selector_primary"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
                />
            <View
                android:id="@+id/extra_view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:visibility="gone"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
mSpinner.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            /// hide keyboard 
                InputMethodManager imm=(InputMethodManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(mEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);
                return false;
            }
        }) ;
```